# c# how to mock code line with several properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, properties, mocking, moq

I have this code:

```
Class VM
{
    var MyVm;

    public VM(ExternalEntities externalEntities){
        MyVm = externalEntities.Reflcation.VM;
    }

    public bool IsVmPowerOn(){
        //Do something  
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestVM()
{
    private Mock<IExternalEntities> m_externalEntities = new Mock<IExternalEntities>();
    private Mock<IReflection> m_reflection = new Mock<IReflection>();
    private Mock<IVm> m_vm= new Mock<IVm>();

    m_externalEntities.Setup(x => x.Reflaction).Return(m_reflection.object);
    m_reflection.Setup(x => x.VM).Return(m_vm.Object);

    var testee = new VM(externalEntity.Object)
    var ans = testee.IsVmPowerOn();

    Assert.IsTrue(ans);
}
```

The problem is that `externalEntities.Reflcation` is `null` and the test throws a `NullReferenceException` so it can't activate the Vm property.
The test can't pass constructor.

The following code also throws a `NullReferenceException`:

```
m_externalEntities.Setup(x => x.Reflaction.VM).Return(m_vm.object);
```

How do you test this kind of code?
Why do I receive null after the setup and not the mock object?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `var testee = new VM(m_externalEntities.Object)` instead of `var testee = new VM(externalEntity.Object)`?

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

You had a lot of compilation errors and missing pieces in your code. It was not compiling as-is. That being said, I fixed it up for you. Not sure what your trying to accomplish but this works.

```
public interface IVm
{
    IVm MyVm { get; set; }
}

public class VM : IVm
{
    public IVm MyVm { get; set; }
    public VM(IExternalEntities externalEntities)
    {
        MyVm = externalEntities.Reflaction.VM;
    }

    public bool IsVmPowerOn()
    {
        //Do something
        return true;
    }

}

public interface IExternalEntities
{
    IReflection Reflaction { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalEntities : IExternalEntities
{
    public IReflection Reflaction { get; set; }

    public ExternalEntities()
    {
        Reflaction = new Reflection();
    }
}

public interface IReflection
{
    IVm VM { get; set; }
}

public class Reflection : IReflection
{
    public IVm VM { get; set; }

    public Reflection()
    {
        VM = new VM(null);
    }
}
```

Then using that, your test would look like this.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestVM()
    {
        Mock<IExternalEntities> m_externalEntities = new Mock<IExternalEntities>();
        Mock<IReflection> m_reflection = new Mock<IReflection>();
        Mock<IVm> m_vm = new Mock<IVm>();

        m_externalEntities.Setup(x => x.Reflaction).Returns(m_reflection.Object);
        m_reflection.Setup(x => x.VM).Returns(m_vm.Object);

        var testee = new VM(m_externalEntities.Object);
        var ans = testee.IsVmPowerOn();

        Assert.IsTrue(ans);
    }
```